# How do I get AutoMapper to map this?

Tags: automapper

Say I have this class:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
    public List<User> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

When I use AutoMapper to map the Account class, I would also like it to map the Enterprise class, and the list of users (UserList) in the returned object. How can I get AutoMapper to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoMapper does that out of-the-box if you provide a configuration for the Enterprise and User type.

Configuration looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Account, AccountDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Enterprise, EnterpriseDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
```

This shows how to how collections get mapped:
http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home

Comment: If can give me the actual code to do this, I'll mark it up and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap<Account, AccountDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Enterprise, EnterpriseDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a mapping for each pair of types you would like mapped.

Mapper.CreateMap<Account, AccountDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Enterprise, EnterpriseDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();

Order is not important.